# SPA & Accessible Rich Internet Applications (ARIA)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, wai-aria

I have a single page web application (SPA) built using AngularJS with Text-to-Speech (TTS) support.  On initial app load, TTS works as it should. The DOM element is highlighted, and audio describing the DOM element is played.

The problem is, as soon a new view is loaded in via `ng-view` , TTS no longer works, and the highlight from the previous ng-view elements stays on the screen.

I suspect that this because of how SPA handles navigation, it is done via a partial reload (swapping out `ng-view`).

Any ideas on how to get ARIA and TTS to play nice in a SPA ?

Example view 1 :

```
<a href="some_link/videos">videos</a>
<a href="some_link/ratings">ratings</a>
```

Example view 2 :

```
<a href="some_link/subscriptions">subscriptions</a>
<a href="some_link/playlist">playlist<
```

Loading view 1 would prompt TTS to respond with :

```
// videos , link
// ratings, link
```

Loading view 2 should prompt TTS to respond with :

```
// subscriptions, link
// playlist, link
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `ngAria` module provides support for common ARIA attributes that convey state or semantic information about the application for users of assistive technologies, such as screen readers. For more information, see [AngularJS ngAria API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria).

Comment: @georgeawg Sure . I added some very basic html code, Ill check out the angular aria link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating the DOM with new text, then take a look at the `aria-live` attribute.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live

For example, if you have

```
<a href="some_link/videos">videos</a>
```

and you're using JS to change "videos" to "subscriptions", then all you need is `aria-live="polite"` on the link:

```
<a href="some_link/videos" aria-live="polite">videos</a>
```

Now if you change the text, a screen reader will read the new text.